# Unexpected response while ploting using matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a simple sine wave using the module matplotlib in Python.My code is as follows

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import scipy as sp
>>> import matplotlib.pylab as plt
>>> t = np.linspace(0,0.02,100)
>>> from math import pi
>>> y = np.sin(2*pi*50*t)
>>> plt.plot(t,y)
```

But for this code I'm getting the following response.

```
matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0xb0243ec
```

The plot is not generated. What does this mean?

[Issue Update]

I used the function show() as mentioned in the answer below.It worked fine.I changed the x and y values to the following values

```
  >>> x = [[1.6667,2.815,3.926,4.4,5.295,5.9256,7.827,8.888, 9.11,11.56]]
  >>> y = [[ 10.45356339,11.18586915,11.94317905,12.28168673,12.94723261,13.43770791,15.03196546,16.00241726,16.21326609,18.7330932]]
  >>> plt.plot(x,y)
```

The response I got was

matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x960f1cc>, , , , , , , , ,

I then used the function show()

> > > plt.show()

The plot window opened.But I couldn't see the curve.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Where are you doing this, in the command line or in IPython? I'm assuming the latter, so just use prepend your code with `%pylab inline`.

Comment: No I'm doing it in the command line

Comment: Your second issue is caused by the `[[` and `]]` around your list: you're creating a `list` inside a `list`. Use one set of `[` ...`]` and your example plots fine.

Comment: Please do not import `pylab`, use `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` instead.

Comment: The `Line2D..` is the repr of the objects returned be the call to plot.

Answer (score 1):

The first example on [this](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html) page may be informative:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

It looks like your logic is right, you just need to call plt.show().

Comment: Hi,I'm facing an issue when I try plotting multiple floating point numbers.Why is this?I've updated this in the question

Comment: @JoseKurian I'm no expert on matplotlib. I think you'd be best accepting my answer to your first question, editing out your second question, and then posting it as another question. You'll get way more response that way!